# Angularfire - $scope wont update after async call, and $apply throws error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am currently banging my head trying to understand a little bit better how Angularfire works in this case. I have 2 controllers on my "webapp/test", one for the user to login, and the other to show some profile info. After the user login with Facebook, i use the "uid" to check the firebase DB if the user exist, and retrieve some of the info thats saved on the database.

The problem right now if since the database read call is async, i cant get the info to update on the view, and using `$scope.$apply()` only works as long as i dont change pages, once i click on a page thats using another controller, i get the following:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$rootScope/inprog?p0=%24digest
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller("profile", function($scope, loginService, Auth, userManagement) {
    var authData = Auth.$getAuth();
    if (authData != null) {
        $scope.authData = authData;
        userManagement.saveLastLogin(authData);
        userManagement.userDatabaseRead(authData).done(function(userDatabase) {
                $scope.userDatabase = userDatabase;
                $scope.$apply();
        });
    };
    $scope.logoutFB = function() {
        loginService.logoutUser();
        Auth.$onAuth(function(authData) {
            $scope.authData = authData;
        });
    };
})
```

**Factory**

```
app.factory("userManagement",function(FirebaseUrl) {
    return {
        saveLastLogin: function(authData) {
            var userId = authData.uid;
                var ref = new Firebase(FirebaseUrl);
                var users = ref.child("users");
                var timestamp = Date.now();
                users.child(authData.uid).update({
                    last_activity: timestamp,
                });
                console.log('user ' + userId + ' last login was on' + timestamp);
        },
        userDatabaseRead: function(authData) {
            var ref = new Firebase(FirebaseUrl+"users/"+authData.uid);
            var data, def = $.Deferred();
            ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
                var userDatabase = snapshot.val();
                def.resolve(userDatabase);
            }, function (errorObject) {
              console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
            });
            return def.promise();
        },
    }
});
```

**Update 1: View**

This is my view, what i am trying to do is once the user is logged in, show some information from the firebase structure that belongs to this user `uid`

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <h1>Profile View</h1>
  <p ng-show="authData">Welcome {{ authData.facebook.cachedUserProfile.first_name }}</p>
  <p ng-show="authData">{{userDatabase.last_activity | date:'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z'}}</p>
  <button ng-click="logoutFB()" ng-show="authData" class="btn btn-danger facebook-login">Logout</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add the view code for a better understanding of what you are trying to do?

Comment: @AndréKool hi Andre! just updated with the view code and a brief explanation, thanks!

Comment: Why you are even using `$scope.$apply()`? It doesn't look like you are updating scope values out of angular scope, please correct if I'm wrong

Comment: @rahilwazir yes, im actually updating the user last activity on another piece of code, and the callback for that brings new data to the scope that its not reflecting on the view. Still, like i suspected i have a much bigger problem with how the code is structured (per David post)

Comment: Another alternative is instead of using `$apply`, defer the `$scope` update to the next digest cycle using **`$timeout`**. This has worked wonders for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not actually using [AngularFire](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html), just the Firebase SDK.

Angular is not aware of the Firebase SDK, so you need to use AngularFire so it triggers the $digest loop for you.

To includle AngularFire, add the JavaScript file and then add it to the dependency array as well.

```
angular.module('app', ['firebase'])
  .constant('FirebaseUrl', '<my-firebase-app>')
  .service('rootRef', ['FirebaseUrl', Firebase])
  .factory('userManagement', UserManagement)
  .controller('MyCtrl', MyController);

function UserManagement($firebaseObject, rootRef) {
  return {
    saveLastLogin: saveLastLogin,
    userDataseRead: userDatabaseRead
  };

  function userDataseRead(authData) {
    var userRef = rootRef.child('users').child(authData.uid);
     // return a $firebaseObject with the ref, don't create a listener
    return $firebaseObject(userRef);
  }

  function saveLasLogin(authData) {
     // this code is good because it doesn't do any listening,
     // just updates to the server
  }
}

function MyController($scope, userManagement) {
  var authData = Auth.$getAuth();
  $scope.userDatabase = userManagement(authData);
}
```

#### Some things to note in your original code.

**You're using a Promise is a real time listener, which is an anti-pattern.**

Promises fire off only once, whereas Firebase database listeners can fire off multiple times.

```
ref.on("value", function(snapshot) {
  var userDatabase = snapshot.val();
  def.resolve(userDatabase); // don't do this
 }, function (errorObject) {
  console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
});
```

AngularFire takes care of this for you when you use either a `$firebaseObject` or `$firebaseArray`.

**Use `resolve` in the router to inject users**

[Rather than grab the user in the controller, you can ensure that if the user is authenticated they will be injected in the controller:](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/guide/user-auth.html#section-routers)

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider) {
$routeProvider.when("/home", {
  controller: "HomeCtrl",
  templateUrl: "views/home.html",
  resolve: {
    currentAuth: ["Auth", function(Auth) {
      return Auth.$requreAuth();
    }]
  }
})
```

Comment: Using `resolve` is awesome. I really makes life much easier. You can resolve anything that is a promise. So you can also resolve `$firebaseObject`s and `$firebaseArray`s with their `$loaded()` functions as well.